# How to increase grails2.0.4 performance in Development mode?

Tags: performance, grails-2.0.4

I am working with grails framework. It takes too much time to respond a request from browser. Due to this issue i have to restart the server too many times. I will highly appreciate for your accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may suffer from performance issues due to insufficient memory (heap). In this case you will need increase the maximum heap size. You can use the [Grails JavaMelody plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/grails-melody) , which integrates [JavaMelody](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) system monitoring tool into grails application, in order to tack such issues.

To increase the maximum heap size when running the application with the run-app command add the following vm option: `-Xmx1024m`

If running with the run-war command add the following to your BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.tomcat.jvmArgs = ['-Xmx1g']
```

In both cases set the maximum heap size according to your needs.